# PySpark - Transform multiple columns without using udf

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a df like this one:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [("1", "Apple", "cat"), ("2", "2.", "house"), ("3", "<strong>text</strong>", "HeLlo 2.5")],
        ["id", "text1", "text2"])
```

```
+---+---------------------+---------+
| id|                text1|    text2|
+---+---------------------+---------+
|  1|                Apple|      cat|
|  2|                   2.|    house|
|  3|<strong>text</strong>|HeLlo 2.5|
+---+---------------------+---------+
```

multiple functions to clean text like

```
def remove_html_tags(text):
    document = html.fromstring(text)
    return " ".join(etree.XPath("//text()")(document))

def lowercase(text):
    return text.lower()

def remove_wrong_dot(text):
    return re.sub(r'(?<!\d)[.,;:]|[.,;:](?!\d)', ' ', text)
```

and a list of columns to clean

```
COLS = ["text1", "text2"]
```

I would like to apply the functions to the columns in the list and also keep the original text

```
+---+---------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
| id|                text1|text1_clean|    text2|text2_clean|
+---+---------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|  1|                Apple|      apple|      cat|        cat|
|  2|                   2.|          2|    house|      house|
|  3|<strong>text</strong>|       text|HeLlo 2.5|  hello 2.5|
+---+---------------------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

I already have an approach using UDF but it is not very efficient. I've been trying something like:

```
rdds = []
    for col in TEXT_COLS:
        rdd = df.rdd.map(lambda x: (x[col], lowercase(x[col])))
        rdds.append(rdd.collect())
    return df
```

My idea would be to join all rdds in the list but I don't know how efficient this would be or how to list more functions.

I appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

**EDIT:** Not all transformations can be done with regexp_replace. For example, the text can include nested html labels and in that case a simple replace wouldn't work or I don't want to replace all dots, only those at the end or beginning of substrings

Comment: do a regexp_replace with a loop: `for col in COLS: df = df.withColumn(col,F.regexp_replace(....your replace code ...))`

Comment: Not all transformations that I want to apply are replacement of substrings so regexp_replace wouldn't be enough

Comment: It will he helpful if you can edit your question to include a sample of your original usecase but only a sample so it doesn't make the question big. This will help us reproduce the ask and answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: I edited the question. Hope is more clear now

Answer (score 0):

Spark built-in functions can do all the transformations you wanted

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

cols = ["text1", "text2"]

for c in cols:
    df = (df
        .withColumn(f'{c}_clean', F.lower(c))
        .withColumn(f'{c}_clean', F.regexp_replace(f'{c}_clean', '<[^>]+>', ''))
        .withColumn(f'{c}_clean', F.regexp_replace(f'{c}_clean', '(?<!\d)[.,;:]|[.,;:](?!\d)', ''))
    )

+---+--------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
| id|               text1|    text2|text1_clean|text2_clean|
+---+--------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|  1|               Apple|      cat|      apple|        cat|
|  2|                  2.|    house|          2|      house|
|  3|<strong>text</str...|HeLlo 2.5|       text|  hello 2.5|
+---+--------------------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```